# Контейнеры map/set и кэш процессора

Tags: c++, оптимизация, stl, c++17

В книге Артур О'Двайр "Осваиваем C++17 STL"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на стр.104 наткнулся на удивительное заявление:

> Мудрость, накопленная в пост-C++11 мире, гласит, что std::map и
>   std::set, будучи основанными на деревьях указателей, настолько
>   недружественные к кешу процессора, что их всегда желательно избегать и
>   взамен использовать std::unordered_map и std::unordered_set.

Рекомендация использовать хеш таблицы вместо сбалансированных деревьев вне зависимости от контекста использования настолько сомнительна, что ее вряд ли имеет смысл обсуждать. Интереснее фраза, что якобы хеш-таблицы гораздо лучше деревьев вписываются в кеш. У меня по этому поводу возник вопрос - это действительно так? В самом деле существует какая-то достоверная статистика, или же это очередное открытие британских ученых?

Comment: То, что кеш побивает асимптотику, действительно, факт. А вот что лучше вписывается в кеш, не могу сказать.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, вот чисто из бытовых, так сказать, соображений, я бы сказал, что скорее хэш-таблицы в кеш не впишутся. Но наверняка вряд ли скажешь без серьезного тестирования. Мне так кажется, что О'Двайр свою рекомендацию из пальца высосал, но вдруг кто-то действительно этот вопрос исследовал.

Comment: А приводит ли автор в этой книге mcve демонстрирующий это поведение? Какие-то конкретные цифры? Если нет, то можете смело игнорировать этот текст. Если подобные голословные утверждения разбросаны по всей книге, то можете смело ее выкидывать.

Comment: @VTT, если бы там было какое-то обоснование, я бы здесь этот вопрос не задавал. Это цитата целиком, на ней заканчивается глава. Ну а насчет выкидывать - если выкидывать все книги с необоснованными утверждениями, то мне их на помойку не перетаскать. Даже известные и уважаемые авторы нет-нет да ляпнут что-нибудь этакое. Начиная со Страуструпа, кстати - вот уж кто любит поучить жизни.

Answer (score 1):

При однократном поиске в хэш-таблице без синонимов будет прочитано 2 линии кэша *(если так получилось, что данные по выравниванию не поместились в одну линию, то 3 линии кэша)*, а для дерева очевидно, что больше, особенно если в узлах дерева хранятся указатели на ключи (а не сами ключи).

Если поисков много, активность (в смысле количества активных процессов в системе, которые будут "вымывать" ваши данные из кэша) низкая, то искомые данные для обеих структур окажутся в кэше и повторные поиски будут быстрее.

Но и здесь, очевидно, что хэш-таблица будет быстрее.

Интересно, что для маленького дерева, которое вместе с данными (ключами) размещается в 2-х *последовательных* линиях кэша (128 байт, последовательно размещенными в памяти с адреса, кратного 64) даже 4 обращения к памяти (корень, ключ в корне, потомок, его ключ) могут занять меньше времени, чем 2 обращения к памяти для хэш-таблицы (там наверняка указатель из таблицы и данные будут сильно разнесены по адресам), поскольку ОС может устанавливить политику доступа к кэшу для опережающего последовательного чтения линий кэша.

Comment: Можно поподробнее про "При однократном поиске в хэш-таблице без синонимов будет прочитано 2 строки кэша"? Почему именно две?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, первая линия кэша это чтение вычисленного по хэш-функции указателя, вторая -- данные по указателю (это если писать хэш-таблицы нормально, а как в крестах написано -- не знаю)

Comment: Завтра попробую сделать простой тест. Я вот только давно с железом дела не имею, так что вопрос - команды invd хватит для очистки кеша или надо что-то посложнее?

Comment: @freim, а зачем его чистить в таком тесте?

Comment: После заполнения set и unordered_set надо бы чистить все кеши перед тестами на поиск.

Comment: "_а как в крестах написано -- не знаю_" - там не так просто, и двумя чтениями вряд ли получится обойтись. Да и коллизии тоже как-то повлияют.

Comment: @freim, да, понял идею. Можно просто заполнить кэш (взять массив на несколько мегабайт и memset()-нуть) каким-то мусором после построения дерева/таблиц

Comment: основное свойство хеш-таблицы — константное время доступа, будет выполняться, что с кешем, что без ;)

Comment: *"очевидно, что хэш-таблица будет быстрее"* - *"лихой скачок через барьер несуразицы, совершенно ошеломляющий нормальный разум"*. Без конкретных примеров и измерений это такие же голословные утверждения, как в обсуждаемой книге.

Comment: @VTT, каждое обращение к DRAM это сотни (может быть и ближе к тысяче) тактов CPU.(L2 cache десяток-другой) Вот и считайте

Comment: @Fat-Zer, вот поэтому и непонятно как проверить именно кеширование. Я вот думаю над тестом, и что-то ничего в голову не приходит.

Comment: @freim Эффективность кэширования можно оценить при помощи профилирования (кто бы мог подумать). Можно использовать cachegrind (синтетический тест эмулирующий машину), perf ([Hardware cache events and perf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52170960/hardware-cache-events-and-perf)) или инструменты intel vtune.

Comment: @VTT, не думаю, что профилирование поможет разобраться отдельно с кешем. perf это вроде как чисто линуксовая вещь, а остальное перечисленное сложновато. Я готов выделить часок на написание несложного теста, но тратить кучу времени на освоение нового инструмента и полноценное исследование просто не могу. Так что я пас, пожалуй.

Comment: @VTT, только вот «честно» сравнить их будет сложно... и ежу понятно, что числовые результаты по промахам у дерева достаточного размера в среднем будут куда хуже — там больше и алгоритмических накладных расходов (логорифмическая сложность и такое же количество обращений к памяти), да и просто по памяти — 3 указателя на каждый элемент вместо одного у хеша, а при реальной работе с обычным аллокатором и локальность страдает, так что эффективный размер кеша сжимается в 2—8 раз.